# mtklog folder and how to read logs in it

Tags: fastboot, logging

Ok, so, I have folder called mtklog in which are few folders named like "db.fatal.00.HW_Reboot" inside there are 2 files ZZ_INTERNAL and db.fatal.00.HW_Reboot.dbg it seems like .dbg file is some archive and it have logs in it but when I try to read those logs it asks for password, how figure out what is password? Just to say those .dbg files are created at time when I try to fastboot boot something and it ends up failing so I need to see those logs to figure out what is wrong.